# Vue packages version mismatch with Laravel

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, npm

I'm having this trouble and I need your help. Here's my **package.json** file

```
"dependencies": {
...
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
...
}
```

and when y execute `npm install` and I check for the vue and the vue-template-compiler packages  in my *node_modules* folder there are both the same version (2.6.11). But here is my problem, when I load my site I have this error message:

> Error: Module build failed: 
> Error:
> Vue packages version mismatch:
>
> - vue@2.6.11
>
> - vue-template-compiler@2.5.2
>
> This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
> If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
> If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

So I checked the version of the **vue-loader** I have in my *node_modules* and its version is higher 10.0, so I executed `npm update vue-template-compiler` just as it says at the error message, but it not makes any changes (because in my *node_modules* folder I alredy have the correct version).

I checked the current version of vue-template-compiler in the [NPMJS site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler) and is 2.6.11, as like as the current vue version.

I tried delete the *node_modules* folder and re-install with `npm install`, I tried delete *node_modules* folder + **package-lock.json** file and re-install, I tried execute `npm update` and re-install, I deleted my browser's cache. I tried everything I found related with my problem, but nothing worked. So here I am, if anybody knows what could be happening please help, I don't know what to do anymore. I'm using Laravel 5.5.

Comment: Did you recompile your assets after installing? `npm install`, then `npm run dev` (or `npm run watch`)

Comment: yeah, I did npm run dev, I forgot say that. Didn't tried with npm run watch, I'll try now.

Comment: `npm run watch` runs `npm run dev` when affected files have changed, so this'll probably not work too if `npm run dev` failed

Comment: Wow @kerbh0lz you save my life, that solved my problem, it throw 2 warnings with 2 missing libraries that I was using in my app (and probably deleted in one of my tests). That solved my problem. Thanks! :)